# Symfony2 Form ChoiceType [radio buttons]

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm here with a quick question, because I can't figure out if I'm doing something wrong or `Symfony2 Forms` component does not work consistently. The scenario is as follows:

- I have a form with custom form type [`ChoiceType` "child" type] with some predefined values
- I need this custom form type to have default value selected when no value has been selected before [so the form has not yet been submitted]
- Then again, I may also have this form prepopulated based on user's settings [preferences]

What I would expect to happen:

1. No user preferences - form field has default value [0]
2. User preferences available - form field has value passed in `$data` parameter [0-7]
3. Form is being submitted - the value of form field is the one that has been submitted  [0-7]

What actually happens:

- If form field is set to be select `['expanded' => false]` it works as expected for both display (first value [0] is selected - probably because it's the first one) and submission (0 is being submitted)
- If form field is radio button list `['expanded' => true]` none of the values are selected to begin with and submitting the form does not submit any value either.

Can someone explain me how to make radio button selected? I can use `empty_data` to set the value if none is submitted, but what about initial form display? It would be perfect to make the selection (for both select boxes and radio buttons) based on `empty_value`.

I also can't use `data` option, because it will overwrite any data passed to form (see point 2 above) as well as data submitted.

@EDIT

I would like to avoid two things:

- using JavaScript is definitely not an option
- overriding the template is something I'd like to avoid as well, mainly because I'm currently using bootstrap theme as a foundation which is going to be replaced by proper frontend / templates later

Comment: You're right, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31573320/1970395) answer should do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question.
To manage the form default value, you only need to set the property of the object mapped.

For example:

```
$formObject->child->attributeDefault = "defaultValue";
if($hasPreference) {
  $formObject->child->attribute1 = "preferenceDefautlValue"
}
$form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType(), $formObject);

$form->handleRequest($request) //overide default value by submitted one
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But form initial form display, if no user preferences are exposed, this `mapped object` (an array actually) is null. Do you suggest I should include defaults there as well? It does seem like one solution, but I'd prefer to keep everything within the scope of field type if possible