# Form field default value with DataTransformer

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I can't set the default value of a form field that has a DataTransformer attached to it.

Let's take the example from the [official documentation on DataTransformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html):

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('issue', TextType::class)
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Task::class,
    ));
}
```

In the example, a ModelTransformer is added to the 'issue' field, transforming the Issue object into a string (the issue number) when rendering the form, and transforming it back to an Issue upon form submission.

Now I'm setting a default value for the issue field through the builder options:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $issue = $options['issue']; //$issue contains an Issue Object from the controller
    $builder
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('issue', TextType::class, array(
            'data' => $issue
        ))
    ;
}
```

When rendering the form I get the following error:

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class AppBundle/Entity/Issue, but is a(n) string. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) string to an instance of AppBundle/Entity/Issue.

- Dumping $issue returns an Issue object
- Setting the data_class option to null as suggested returns the same error
- Passing $issue->getId() instead of $issue gets me the following error: "Call to a member function getId() on integer"

I really don't understand this error, I hope you'll be able to help !

Comment: I think you're wrong. You seem to want to pass an object to a text field which by definition can only take a string as a parameter. Maybe it works if your object has a method __toString() but I do not think it's logical.

Comment: @AlphonseD. I thought so, but passing $issue->getId() instead of $issue as 'data' value throws another Exception saying that getId() can't be called on string values whereas it IS NOT a string when dumped in the buildForm() function so I was really confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IssueSelectorType` (child of `TextType`) expects a string as initial value and the data transformer inside, converts this to issue instance, so you need to pass the issue id instead.

However, `data` option does not works as default value always:

> The default values for form fields are taken directly from the underlying data structure. The data option overrides this default value ([Doc.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#data))

See this answer for more details: [How to set a default value in a Symfony 2 form field?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31573320/4224384)

Comment: That was also my first guess, passing the the issue id instead, but  then i get "Call to a member function getId() on integer" because my ModelTransformer tries to transform it to an integer. Does this mean the only way to set a default value for the field when using a DataTransformer is through setData() ?

Comment: I tried using your FormExtension solution and i'm still getting the same error